# Is it possible to show a cardinal direction button in the navigation bar of Bing Maps v8?

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

The navigation bar of v7 offers among others a cardinal direction button (see screenshot below). Does this option exist in v8?

[image: Bing v7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8 does not provide such buttons, however you can easily create this for your app if you want. Here is a code sample: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#CustomOverlay_BasicOverlay

This sample uses a custom overlay for the buttons, but you could easily use HTML in a div and just float it above the map. That would take less code since you would create the buttons using HTML rather than JavaScript.